# How to make Pycharm work with breakpoints and get all the environment of Amplify mock

Tags: python, pycharm, aws-amplify

I'm pretty new to Python, pycharm and Amplify but I am familiar with the JetBrains IDE, just with other programming languages.

If I run the `Amplify mock function <functionName>` I get the function running locally and pulling information just as if it was on the server from what it looks like.

If I just run the pycharm normal debugger I can get to run the file but I have to add code to make it call the default function which is just called `handler` but even before it gets to the function it's obvious that's it's not picking up the environment the same as running `amplify mock`.

Is there a way to use the breakpoints in pycharm and get debugging capabilities of the JetBrains IDE and have it run fully mocked? And if so, how?

Thanks.